# Video height and weight

Tags: html, video

I'm trying create a site where there are multiple on video on one page, basically a new video will be on the bottom after one like the image shown below.

This is a two separate video, the problem is i cant find a way for all the video to have a standard size. both video has same width and height, here is the snippet:

```
src="file://D:/src1.mp4" 
tabindex = "0" controls = "controls" loop ="true
width="320" height="240"> 

src="file://D:/src2.mp4" 
tabindex = "0" controls = "controls" loop ="true
width="320" height="240">
```

What i see is the other video is not the same at all, what i just want it for both of them to have the same size both before and on playing.
Note: I not yet eligible to post an image

Comment: Please post all the relevant code. it seems here that your missing the start of the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Add this, you can re-size it by changing height & weight-

```
<video src="file://D:/src1.mp4" tabindex = "0" controls = "controls" loop ="true" width="300" height="240"></video>
```

Few tag was missing from your code. Hope it works now!

Comment: You're right that missing "" has an effect, it now perfectly same size with 320 by 240 somehow when i tried to double the size it is noticeable that the first on is not totally fit all all. The second didn't completely fit on the bottom so there are gap between the control area.

Comment: Try this, you can make video control size more than 800px-                  <video id="sampleMovie" width="800" height="360" preload controls>
 <source src="HTML5Sample_H264.mov" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
 <source src="HTML5Sample_Ogg.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
 <source src="HTML5Sample_WebM.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
</video>